# Touchpad drivers get uninstalled after every restart

Tags: drivers, windows-8.1, touchpad

I have a 900x3c (a01) Samsung laptop. I recently updated it to Windws 8.1. Now every time I reboot the machine, the system seems to fall back to default drivers for my touchpad and I have to install and setup the advanced Elan drivers all over again. What can I do to make the system remember the driver?